# Filter data by column using user input value in python

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I wanted to filter the data from a CSV file based on a value from the column SN. The column value is given by the user itself. I am using the below code but the same returns no values. Can someone please correct this? . The issue is in the line is_data = (data['SN'] == SN) The code works fine when I replace the SN with a value from the table

Below are the data and code
[data image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzd4B.png)

Expected output : Ex if the value is 1024314 the output should be [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Cnz.png)

```
   import pandas as pd
SN = input("insert SN number")

print(SN)

data = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
is_data = (data['SN'] == SN)
print(is_data.head())
data_filter = data[is_data]
print(data_filter.shape)
print(data_filter.head())
```

Comment: Does `data['SN']` contain strings or ints?

Comment: Could you post your data as text rather than image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns a string and you are comparing it to integers. You should cast `SN` to integer:

```
data = pd.read_csv("sample.csv") is_data = (data['SN'] == int(SN))
```